# KeyPressed method doesn't update when player turns (rotates)

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I'm wondering how to make it so the head of the ship (the player) updates the direction that the ship is going. Currently it works like this:

- The player holds the up/down arrow key and the right/left arrow key at the same time which causes the ship to continue in the same direction it started off in, but this only rotates the ship around its center while its moving. I want it so while the player holds the up/down arrow key and the left/right arrow key at the same time, it will move in the direction the player is facing.

Here is my current code:

```
     if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        rotateRight = true;
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        rotateLeft = true;
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        player.setDY(5*Math.cos(player.rotation));
        player.setDX(-5*Math.sin(player.rotation));
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        player.setDY(-5*Math.cos(player.rotation));
        player.setDX(5*Math.sin(player.rotation));
        //System.out.println("x,y: " + player.x + "," + player.y + ", Rotation: " + player.rotation + ", DX: " + player.getDX() + ", DY: " + player.getDY());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by changing the above code to:

```
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        rotateRight = true;
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        rotateLeft = true;
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down = true;
    }if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up = true;
    }
```

so that all these boolean values are dealt with in the Player class and not the KeyInput class -- it must be because Player class is updated 60 times per second and the KeyInput class is only called on KeyPressed (must be manually called).